# What is the correct "order" of the double integral in the definition of $F_{X,Y}(x,y) $, the distribution function of (X,Y)?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

In the notes I'm working through it says that for the cumulative distribution function of the bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$

"$$F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)= \int_{-\infty}^{x_0}\int_{-\infty}^{y_0}f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy $$
where $(x_o,y_0)$ is a value in the range of (X,Y)"

But shouldn't it be:
$$F_{X,Y}(x_0,y_0)= \int_{-\infty}^{x_0}\int_{-\infty}^{y_0} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx \text{ ?}$$

Comment: both give the same result and the first (inner) integral is over $y$ and associated with $d y$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} \require{cancel}
\text{wrong: } & \xcancel{\int_{-\infty}^{x_0} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{y_0} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx\right) \, dy\quad} \\[10pt]
\text{right: } & \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{y_0} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \right) \, dx \\[10pt]
\text{right: } & \int_{-\infty}^{y_0} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx\right) \, dy \\[10pt]
\text{right: } & \iint\limits_{(x,y)\,:\, x\,\le\,x_0\ \&\ y\,\le\,y_0} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, d(x,y) \\[10pt]
\text{wrong: } & \xcancel{\iint\limits_{(x,y)\,:\, x\,\le\,y_0\ \&\ y\,\le\,x_0} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, d(x,y)}
\end{align}
What is in the notes is wrong.

Comment: What if the notes author said, by way of excuse, "when I wrote $dxdy$ I obviously meant the same thing you wrote as $d(x,y)$ in your 4th expression" ?

Comment: @kimchilover : Then the author of the notes would be wrong. And if the author of the notes tried to work with actual concrete instances of iterated integrals while doing things that way, then the author of the notes would be unable to do anything.

Comment: You never write $dxdy$ for 2-d Lebesgue measure, then, as in $\iint_A dxdy = m(A)$?  Disclaimer: I am not the author of the notes, and was in the midst of drafting a reply along the lines of yours.  But: outside of the context of stating Fubini's theorem, I think you are being pedantically persnickety.

Comment: @kimchilover : If one writes $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure in that way, then how are we to know what $\int_{-\infty}^3 \int_{-\infty}^4$ means? WHICH variable is $\le 3$ and which is $\le4\text{ ?} \qquad$